# Минимальное и максимальное число в списке

Tags: python

> Запросить 5 чисел в список ,и найти в этом списке мин и макс число с
> помощью цикла (запрещено `min`, `max`, `sorted`, `sort`). Вывести эти
> числа

```
A = []
    max = ''
    min = ''
    a = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
    c = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
    d = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
    e = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
    f = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
    A += a,c,d,e,f
    for i in A:
        if i == max:
            max += i
        else:
            min += i
    
    print(f'Максимальное: {max}' , f'Минимальное: {min}' )
```

Зашел в тупик. Разъясните где не прав.

Comment: А зачем вы максимальное и мин. число делаете строкой? И зачем вы проверяете на равенство..

Comment: Вот [тут](https://gospodaretsva.com/max.html) почитайте подробнее как находить

Comment: В max должно быть наименьшее число из вашего набора данных, к примеру `min = float('-inf')`, а в min наоборот

Comment: @Ovsenka Я пробую :) . Всякие варианты. И этот был последний. Спасибо, решение уже нашлось !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код по сути правильный, нужно было только сделать **5 правок:**

```
A = []
max_ = float('-inf')                        # здесь
min_ = float('inf')                         # здесь
a = int(input('Введите целое число...'))   
c = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
d = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
e = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
f = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
A += a, c, d, e, f
for i in A:
    if i > max_:
        max_ = i                            # здесь 
    if i < min_:                            # здесь
        min_ = i                            # здесь

print(f'Максимальное: {max_}' , f'Минимальное: {min_}' )
```

К тому же я изменил ваши имена `max` и `min` (которые являются именами стандартных функций) на `max_` и `min_`.

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Чтобы найти **самое большое** значение, предположим сначала, что оно **самое малое**:
   переменной `max_` присвоим сначала **самое малое значение.**
2. Потому что в Питоне не существует самое малое *целое* число, мы поможем себе самым малым *вещественным* числом — *отрицательной бесконечностью:* `float('-inf')`.
3. Когда встретится число больше *текущего наибольшего* (`if i > max_:`), текущее наибольшее заменим ним (`max_ = i`).
4. Подобным образом действуем для получения самого *малого* значения.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ! То что нужно!

Comment: @Ihor, не стоит. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно немного подправить свой алгоритм. Примерно как-то так:

```
A = []
for _ in range(5):
    a = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
    A.append(int(a))

m_max = A[0]
m_min = A[0]
for i in A:
    if m_max < i:
        m_max = i
    if m_min > i:
        m_min = i

print(f'Максимальное: {m_max}' , f'Минимальное: {m_min}' )
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас !

Comment: @Ihor Если ответ Вам подошёл нажмите на кнопку "принимаю ответ".

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде существует несколько ошибок:

1. Вы инициализировали переменные `max` и `min` как строки, но вам нужно будет сравнивать числа, поэтому эти переменные должны быть типа `int` или `float`.
2. В цикле `for` вы пытаетесь сравнивать число `i` с переменной `max`, но это не имеет смысла, так как max изначально равно пустой строке. Вместо этого вам нужно сравнивать `i` с переменной max, которая хранит максимальное значение, которое вы нашли на данный момент.
3. В цикле `for` вы пытаетесь добавить число `i` к переменным `max` и `min`, но это неверно, так как вы перезаписываете значения этих переменных. Вместо этого вам нужно сравнивать `i` с значением `max` и `min` и обновлять эти значения, если `i` больше или меньше соответственно.

Для того, чтобы найти минимальное и максимальное число в списке A, вам нужно изменить код следующим образом:

```
A = []
max = float('-inf')  # Максимальное значение инициализируем минимальным возможным значением float
min = float('inf')  # Минимальное значение инициализируем максимальным возможным значением float
a = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
c = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
d = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
e = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
f = int(input('Введите целое число...'))
A += a,c,d,e,f

for i in A:
    if i > max:  # Обновляем значение max, если i больше текущего значения max
        max = i
    if i < min:  # Обновляем значение min, если i меньше текущего значения min
        min = i

print(f'Максимальное: {max}' , f'Минимальное: {min}' )
```

В этом коде мы инициализируем переменные max и min с помощью констант `float('-inf') и float('inf')` соответстнно